# Search Bar in O365 Sharepoint Unable to Search Aspx Files within Team Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, enterprise-search, sharepoint-search

I am attempting to create an FAQ Site using the O365 Sharepoint Teams Site. As part of the FAQ experience, I would like to have the top search bar be able to search aspx sites only within the said site, with the keywords able to look through the title and contents of the sites.

Currently, I have routed the search bar using the Site Collection settings to be `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/pub/_layouts/15/search.aspx` , but this gives me the results of all the sites and even my personal folders and items. The reason why I route it in the first place is because the original settings give me `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/pub/_layouts/15/search.aspx/siteall?q=`, giving no results at all. When I was Googling for answers, I presume that an OOB will allow me to search for results within a site, but apparently that was not the case.

The interesting part about this is that I can achieve the result that I want when I customise the Search Result Sources under the Site Collection Administration, when I Query transform and tested `{searchTerms} Path:"<Sharepoint URL>" File Type:aspx`, but I am unable to replicate that experience to the Search Bar.

Other information:

1. I do not have access to admin centre.
2. I am not able to install PnP due to work security restrictions.
3. I am unable to PowerShell solutions.
4. I have achieved said result before without the abovementioned tools until I messed up some site settings and now I don't know how to replicate it

Please feel free to ask me any questions to troubleshoot this issue and I will furnish as much as I can. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using classic or modern SharePoint?

Comment: Hi @CallumCrowley, I am using the modern Sharepoint.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Search or the class SharePoint search experience?

Comment: I am using the [modern Sharepoint](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/configure-modern-search-results-to-search-all-of-your/td-p/447334) search experience. I presume that the [classic version](https://searchexplained.com/create-configure-search-centers-and-search-pages/) uses the url sites/pub/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx instead?

Comment: The default for a new Team site is to use the Microsoft Search experience. The box will already be scoped to the current site by default (unless you have changed this).

Comment: Hi @CallumCrowley, thanks for the comment. Yes, my new Team site uses the Microsoft search experience. Unfortunately, my OOB does not seem to search the current site by default. It only does so when I am on the pages site.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to retrace my steps and managed to find a way to do so.

The new problem:

- I am unable to have newly joined users (even owners) pull the
  results. For some reason or another, newly joined users can only see
  the search results after visiting the pages for the first time.
- I attempted to expedite the process by reindexing but to no avail. I added them as Owners again in the Advanced Settings for People and Groups, even though they are clearly labelled as Owners when I added new people to the Team site at the sidebar. No dice.

In any case, if anyone is interested in the answer to the original question I posted, here are my step by step:

**Step 1**

1. Site > Site Information > View All Site Settings
2. Site Collection Administration > Search Result Sources
3. Create a "New Result Source"

   - Protocol to be Local Sharepoint
   - Type is Sharepoint Search Results
   - Query Transform format sample: `{searchTerms} Path:"<URL>" FileType:aspx`
4. Select your newly designed result source as default.

**Step 2**

1. Go to Site Collection Administration > Search Settings
2. Search Centre URL: `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/<SiteName>/SitePages`
3. Search Query to Send Queries to Custom Results Page URL:`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/<SiteName>/SitePages/Forms/ByAuthor.aspx`

**Step 3**

1. Go to Search > Result Sources
2. Default the Result Sources provided by the site collection - the same source that was set up in Step 1.

**Step 4**

1. Go to Search > Search Settings
2. Change "which search query results page should queries be sent to?"

   - Send queries to a custom results page URL:

     - `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/<SiteName>/_layouts/15/search.aspx`

**Step 5**

1. Go to Search > Search and offline availability
2. Allow this site to appear in search results
3. Indexing ASPX - always index all web parts on this site
4. Reindex site.
5. OK to save.

With these settings, the search function should be correctly set up.